# Touchpad Issue - Jammy Jellyfish (22.04)

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 5 that had Focal Fossa on it previously. I had to edit the grub file to get the touchpad to work in Fossa. Doing that same process now crashes the system after a reboot. I’ve done all the updates and have combed through other questions but they all deal with different Ubuntu versions or models of laptop. Just wondering if anyone has seen this, or has a suggestion?

Edit to the grub file that worked in Fossa was editing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs”`

Comment: Please edit the question and list the changes you made in your grub file so we know what we're dealing with here, thanks.

Comment: Read here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970056 its broken in linux kernel 5.15 that comes in jammy jellyfish. One workaround can be to downgrade the kernel to 5.13 which comes in focal fossa.